# Meanings of "to find out"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs, false-friend

In Germany, a shop made commercials with the slogan "Come in and found out."

There were many jokes about the meaning of the slogan in Germany.
[Often it was interpreted](http://www.spiegel.de/unispiegel/wunderbar/denglisch-in-der-werbung-komm-rein-und-finde-wieder-raus-a-310548.html) as *Komm rein und finde wieder raus* ("Come in, and find the way out again").

[*Find out* is translated to German](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&search=to%20find%20out) as *herausfinden*. The German *herausfinden* has two meanings: to get out, to detect, but also to find a way.

Has *to find out* also a geographical meaning as in "we were in a labyrinth, but find out our way." or is it a German [false friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Find out

> *vb (adverb)*
>   1. to gain knowledge of (something); learn he found out what he wanted
>   2. to detect the crime, deception, etc., of (someone)

As you can see, it usually means to *find some information/knowledge*.

Therefore, it is indeed a "*false friend*" and never has the additional sense that it can in **German**.

Sources - [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com), @[Hellion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/87/hellion)

Comment: In your second usage, though, you must insert the extra words "our way" (or "the way"). In other words, you can _find your way out_ of a corn maze, but you can't _find out_ a corn maze – not unless you use the term in the first sense, e.g., "We found out a corn maze is opening next week.")

Comment: In your second usage, you are not using the verb phrase "find out", you are using the verb "find" with a noun phrase of "our way out" as its object.  You could just as easily say "we found our way in" or "we found a map".

Comment: @Hellion Well, what do you suggest to improve this answer?

Comment: I'd say that the extra stuff (starting with "however") should be removed; the definition is enough.  Perhaps you could add a line confirming that it is indeed a "false friend" and never has the additional sense that it can in German.

Comment: To mean the extra German meaning is "finding a way out" or "finding exit".